# Personalizar o botão do Fullcalendar

Tags: css, fullcalendar

Estou querendo personalizar o botão do fullcalendar, porém não estou conseguindo. Estou usando o Bootstrap. O código CSS do fullcalendar, coloquei depois do CSS do Bootstrap e antes da tag . Vejam o código abaixo:

**CSS**

```
.fc-right button{
      text-transform: uppercase;
      border-radius: 2px;
      font-size: 13px;
      font-weight: 600;
      transition: box-shadow linear 0.4s;
      background-color: #2196F3;
      border-color: #2196F3;
      margin-top: 10px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 grid-item">
   <div class="card" style="background-color: #F9EAAF">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
         <div class="panel-heading bg-default txt-white">
           <i class="fa fa-calendar fa-lg"></i> Calendário de Eventos
         </div>
   <div class="panel-body">
       <div id='calendario'></div>
   </div>
   <div class="panel-footer" align="center">
     <button class="btn btn-default">Ver todos os eventos</button>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#calendario').fullCalendar({
          height: 250,
          contentHeight: 273,
          editable: false,
          eventLimit: false,
          events: 'eventos.php',
          eventColor: '#dd6777',

          eventClick:  function(event, jsEvent, view) {
          $('#modalTitle').html("<i class=\"fa fa-hand-o-right\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i> " + event.title);
          $('#modalBody').html(event.description);
          $('#eventUrl').attr('href',event.url);
          $('#fullCalModal').modal();
      }
      });
});
```

Ele fica dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E quando passo o mouse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço para que ele pegue a formatação que coloquei acima?

Comment: O que você está usando? Poste seu HTML.

Comment: Dê uma olhada [aqui](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/customButtons/).

Comment: Uma boa seria colocar o seu código no JSfiddle, não da pra saber se voce está usando, se é um hover ou se é um proprio atributo dessa fullcalendar. Ou então colocar aqui mesmo, pra executar.

Comment: Olá Jorge. Tem razão. Coloquei os trechos que se referem ao calendário, já que o HTML está muito grande. Estou usando o Bootstrap.

Comment: Olá Marcelo. Vou tentar isolar o código e colocar no JSfiddle.

Comment: Vc quer que ele mude a aparência ao passar o mouse em cima?

Comment: Olá Leandro, quero implementar o CSS que coloquei no post, mas não estou conseguindo. E se possível, alterar também ao passar o mouse.

Comment: Seria legal se vc coloca-se aqui o Hml inteiro, pois não estou vendo a classe *fc-right button* que vc está aplicando o Css.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver. Abri o CSS do próprio Fullcalendar e alterei essas linhas:

```
.fc button {
    text-transform: uppercase;
      border-radius: 2px;
      font-size: 13px;
      font-weight: 600;
      transition: box-shadow linear 0.4s;
      background-color: #2196F3;
      border-color: #2196F3;
      margin-top: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}


.fc .fc-button-group > * { /* extra precedence b/c buttons have margin set to zero */
    float: left;
    /*margin: 0 0 0 -1px;*/
}

.fc-state-default {
/*
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#ffffff), to(#e6e6e6));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border-color: #e6e6e6 #e6e6e6 #bfbfbf;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    color: #333;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
*/
}
```

Comment: Obrigado a todos.

Comment: Não é bom você editar diretamente o código de uma biblioteca, seria melhor você sobrescrever essas classes em um outro css após o carregamento dela.

Comment: Olá Leandro. Sim, concordo com você, mas infelizmente por algum motivo, ao tentar sobrescrever, não estava surtindo efeito no calendário. Acredito que deve ter sido algum conflito com o template que estou usando. Como vou usar o calendário em apenas uma página, tive que fazer dessa forma, mesmo não sendo boas práticas.

Comment: O problema é que se algum momento, você atualizar essa biblioteca perderá suas customizações.